# What is going on in this shorthand operator?

Tags: javascript, performance, shorthand

I am trying to get better at shorthand.  Can someone help clarify the below?

```
(obj.getValue("title")) ? message += "\ntitle: " + obj.getValue("title") : null;
```

Is it, if obj has a title then add it to the message otherwise it is null?

Comment: You got it! What you're looking at is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Otherwise it returns null. `obj.getValue("title")` might return `0` and it's not null.

Comment: It's an odd use of the ternary operator to be honest, this would be more clearly written as an if statement

Comment: Agreed @aw04.  Pretty sure the `null` is just there to fill the else statement, and just kinda complicates things.  A one line if statement would make much more sense.

Comment: I'm curious where this was found.

Comment: @RobertIngrum so you would just check if it exists, in a if statement else set to null?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it is in a library that I was looking through line by line.  I'm trying to understand more.

Comment: @CoolShape, I would just do `if (obj.getValue('title')) { message += "\ntitle: " + obj.getValue('title'); }`.  Even clearer if you split it to multiple lines, but you might be trying to save space.

Comment: @CoolShape The null isn't actually doing anything here, it's there because it's part of the ternary operator (which is why I said it's a bad use of the operator). So to write this as an if statement, you would omit the else entirely

Comment: But isn't it building the message for title to null if it is not there?

Comment: No, it's appending the title to an existing message if the title exists, if not it's just leaving the message as is

Comment: @aw04 ahhhhh I get it now.  That makes total sense.  So if it doesn't it just leaves message as is.  But yeah then if it doesn't set title to null then why have it at all.

Comment: Yep. I would suggest looking at some examples of the ternary operator and play around with it. Once you understand how it is normally used, I think this will make much more sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's a very odd use of one, since it's not actually using the 'else' part of the operator for anything useful, and would be more clearly written as:

```
if (obj.getValue("title")) {
    message += "\ntitle: " + obj.getValue("title");
}
```

As long as `obj.getValue("title")` is "[truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)", it will modify `message`.

If this is in code you own, take the opportunity to make the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right if obj has a title then add it to the message, but to be strict you should know that value of `obj.getValue("title")` should not be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (`0, null, undefined, '', NaN, false`) to pass the condition.

Also you can use here other option

```
obj.getValue("title") && (message += "\ntitle: " + obj.getValue("title"));
```

If `obj.getValue("title")` has [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value than operation in second parentheses will execute.
Also you can create reference to `obj.getValue("title")`.

```
var title = obj.getValue("title");
title && (message += "\ntitle: " + title);
```

It is better cause in this case method `getValue` executes only once.

Shorthand `+=` prepends value of `obj.getValue("title")` to `message`.